# Is it possible to access instance values within a methods missing function?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to write my first `method_missing` override when I kept running into (edited) *stack level too deep* errors. The main culprit seemed to be trying to utilize an instance attribute. For instance if 'self' was a instance of the User class then checking for something like:

```
def method_missing(name)
  if self.name
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Would seg fault. I spent a long time on this but ended up giving up. There must be something I'm not understanding about accessing it.

#### Edit

My apologies, Andrew is correct, I am getting Stack Level too deep errors. With this in mind, what is the appropriate (if any) way to access the instances attribute values?

Comment: You're getting a *seg fault*?? Do you get a backtrace from it? If so, please post it here. What version of Ruby are you using (`ruby --version`) and on what platform (`uname -a`)?

Comment: `self` is a Ruby keyword that is the same as other languages' `this`. Did you intend to use `self`?

Comment: @Linux_iOS.rb.cpp.c.lisp.m.sh That shouldn't cause a seg fault, though.

Comment: Interesting question. Unlike other languages, there is _always_ a value for `self` in Ruby. What does `p self` print? Does using `@name` work?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall: I know, but other bugs in the code don't help diagnose the segfault.

Comment: Does the "name" method exist, or does it depend on `method_missing`? (i.e. are you causing infinite recursion?)

Comment: @d11wtq *In theory* that should yield "stack level too deep", not a seg fault, but it is possible.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, my apologies, you are correct, I have updated the question to reflect the fact that I am getting "stack level too deep" errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *potentially* rectify this problem by ensuring that `self.name` actually exists:

```
def method_missing(name)
  if self.respond_to?(:name) && self.name
    # do stuff
  end
end
```

Note this *may not* work if your class inherits from anything Railsy (e.g. `ActiveRecord::Base`), since it overrides `respond_to?`.

If you *are* in a Railsy class, your method missing should call `super`, lest you lose a lot of the "magic" ActiveRecord methods (including, probably, `self.name` itself):

```
def method_missing(name, *args, &block)
  if name_is_something_i_should_handle_here
    # do your stuff
  else
    super(name, *args, block) # call parent's method_missing
  end
end
```

Obviously you should replace `name_is_something_i_should_handle_here` with the appropriate logic.

You may also wish to consider using [dynamic method creation instead of `method_missing`](http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/ruby-replace-methodmissing-with-dynamic.html).